# how to use for json path, root('User') without array wrapper in sql server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is what i have tried so far and is throwing error.

```
(select 1 "code"  FOR JSON path) as [User] ,Without_Array_Wrapper
```

I want an output like this.
**{"User":{"code":1}}**

Comment: Is there a broader context? It's trivial to select this string literally (`SELECT '{"User":{"code":1}}'`), it's also trivial to get it with `JSON PATH` (`SELECT 1 AS [User.code] FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER`) but if you need these results from querying a table, the final query may be more complicated (because `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` applies globally).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
select 1 [user.code]  FOR JSON path ,Without_Array_Wrapper
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
SELECT   
   (SELECT 1 Code  FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) as [User]  
FOR JSON PATH,    WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Comment: i am getting output like this:   {"User":"{\"Code\":1}"}...  which i cannot use.Can you please tell another way.